# mac: two shortcuts for the same action

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, shortcuts

I regularly switch between keyboard layouts on my mac. This causes confusion with some shortcuts. Therefore I want to assign two key combinations to one shortcut.

In particular, I have used [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/299241/in-mac-os-what-is-the-keyboard-shortcut-to-switch-between-windows-of-the-same-a/299463#299463?newreg=de3c468a83fa4188a2378bfa6d87d104) to change the "Move focus to next window" shortcut to <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>></kbd>. But now I also want to retain the default <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> for when I use the U.S. keyboard.

How can I accomplish this?